# Hexo: How do you change language?

Tags: hexo

I have read doc below, but didn't get how.
http://hexo.io/docs/localization.html

Anyone knows exacly how ?
I want my blog in either japanese or english.

I tried:

- set lang: to ja-jp
- set lang: to en

Answer (score 2):

Edit your  _config.yml file ,

```
 language: ja-jp
```

You MUST indent with one or more spaces. more info here.

,http://ksck23.github.io/2013/11/25/setup-your-personal-markdown-blog-using-hexo,-deployed-to-github/#.VWmrgqhDR7k

http://hexo.io/docs/localization.html